# recursive access to popup submenus in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I've this recursive submenu created whith VBA:

[image: sample menu]

This menu has been created with recursive CommandBar -> CommandBarControl -> CommandBarButton.

Now, my problem is accesing after creating to second, third or fourth level of the menu.

The first level access is easy:

```
Application.CommandBars("MenuJLECalc").Controls("Insertar").Visible = False
```

The problem comes in second level: I haven't the ".Controls" property available as:

```
Application.CommandBars("MenuJLECalc").Controls("Insertar").Controls("Command").Visible = False
```

What is the right way for accesing to second, third and fourth submenu levels ?

Comment: For me you *can* access the `.Controls` of the third level... `Controls("Command")` are you sure of the key `"Command"`? Also, can you show a snippet how you created the submenus?

Comment: Creating menu:

Set MenuContextual = Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=NombreMenu, Position:=msoBarPopup, Temporary:=True)

Creating submenu:

Set SubMenuContextual = MenuContextual.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)

Creating command

Set Boton = SubMenuContextual.Controls.Add

As you can see, simply

Comment: "Command" is a bar name, Apologize for the confusion. I must assign another alias :)